# Clean proof of Fermat's last theorem for $n=3$

Tags: solution-verification, problem-solving

Suppose $a^3 + b^3  = c^3, \ a,b,c \in \mathbb Z^+\ \ (1),\ $
we can assume: $\ a,b$ and $c$ are coprime.Decompose $c^3 - b ^ 3$ into $(c - b)((c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb) = a ^ 3\  $give us three cases $\ C_{1},C_{2} \ \text{and} \ C_{3}$

$\quad C_{1}\  c - b = a ^ 3,\ $ not reasonable.

$\quad C_{2}\  1 < c - b < a ^ 3$

$\quad C_{3}\  c - b = 1$

$\quad$In Case $C_{2},\ $ we see $(c - b) \mid a ^ 3,\ $then there exists a number $m>1$ divides $(c-b)$ and $a,\ $and we see $m \mid 3cb$

$\quad \quad C_{21}\  m=3,\ m \not\mid c,b$

$\quad \quad C_{22} \implies (c \lor  b,a)>1,\ $conflict our assumption.

$\quad \quad $In Case $C_{21}, \ c-b\,$ will of the form $3^k\,$ on the two sides requires $\,k = 3 u - 1\,$ and $\,a = 3^{u} \, v\,$(contributed by MSE user dxiv). We decompose $c^3 - a ^ 3$ also give us three cases

$\quad \quad \quad C_{211}\  c - a = b ^ 3,\ $ not reasonable

$\quad\quad \quad  C_{212}\  1 < c - a < b ^ 3,\ $  then there exists another $m$ conflict our assumption because of $3$ has already divides $a$

$\quad\quad \quad  C_{213}\  c - a=1,\ $ then we have $(c-1)^3 + (c-3^k)^3=c^3,\ c\ $ must be  even. Decompose $a^3 + b ^ 3$ into $(a + b)((a + b) ^ 2 - 3ab) = c ^ 3\  $give us two cases

$\quad \quad \quad \quad C_{2131},\  a + b = a ^ 3,\ $ not reasonable.

$\quad \quad \quad \quad C_{2132},\ $ if there does not exists another $m$ conflict our assumption then while $c=2^nq$ for some odd $q,\ a+b$ must be equals to $2^{3n},\ $ then we have $a+b=(c-1)+(c-3^k)=2^{3n},\ $the question will be: let t = $ \dfrac{2^{3n}+3^k+1}{2^{n+1}},\ n ,\ k \in \mathbb Z^+\ \  \  (2),\ $ if $t$ is an integer, prove $3$ divides $t\ $(proof see aditional).

$\quad$In Case $C_{3}$, we will have the case same to $C_{213},\ $the only difference is $a,b$ swap position.

Here all cases return false, so $(1)$ is not tenable.

My question is I can't believe the problem is that simple, are there something wrong in my reasoning?

Aditional: MSE user (another Mike)Mike's proof of question $(2)$

HINT: For each integer $k$, note that $(3^k+1)\pmod 8$ is either $2$ [if $k$ is even] or $4$ [if $k$ is odd].

If $(3^k+1) \pmod 8$ is $2$, then for $t$ to be an integer then, note that $n$ cannot be a positive integer. So $t$ is never a positive integer if $(3^k+1)\pmod 8$ is $2$.

If $(3^k+1)\pmod 8$ is $4$ then for $t$ to be an integer, $n$ must be $1$. And so $3n$ must be $3$. But then what do you know about $2^3+1$? What divides $2^3+1$?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Lemme add the question.

Comment: One can show, that $c$ is in the interval $[3^k, 2 \cdot 3^k]$. If you can say something about solutions mod $3^m$ for $m$ large enough, then you might be able to conclude, that there is no solution in this interval mod $3^m$ and hence not in the integers.

Comment: You can also try to adapt one of the elementary proofs of FLT to this case. Maybe they simplify to a short argument, this might be interesting to see.

Comment: How do you get $m \mid 3cb$ in case $C_2$?

Comment: @VTand If $m \not\mid 3cb$ then we start the Case similar to $C2132$, and at last get question $(2)$.

Comment: If $m \not\mid 3ab, 3ac, 3cb\ $ in all the three decomposetions, this is problem need to solve.